# Export a Requeried Subform into Excel

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, export-to-excel

I have a subform named **subform_View_Search** and I Re-queried it based on some user's preference (e.g. filter or find latest date of specific item).

Now, I want to export this modified subform into an user preferred location. I have the following code but I am not sure if I am on the right track and this code 
seems does not work ;~(

```
Private Sub Command_Excel_Inst_Click()
Dim Path As String

Path = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "TempQueryName" & ".xls"

subform_View_Search.Form.RecordSource = SQL
subform_View_Search.Form.Requery

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, "subform_View_Search", Path

End Sub
```

Your help will be appreciated !

This question is different than other questions because I am creating a excel file from SQL instead of from a query.

Here is my second try. 
Here is the code of creating a temp query but there are 2 problems.
1. it gives a run time error 3066
2. My code seems doent work to delete the old temporary query

```
Dim db As Database
Dim Qdf As QueryDef

Dim strQry As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim Path As String

Path = CurrentProject.Path & "\" & "TempQueryName" & ".xls"

strSQL = SQL '<-From public
strQry = "TempQueryName"

Set db = CurrentDb
Set Qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(strQry, strSQL)

DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acExport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, strQry, Path

DoCmd.DeleteObject acQuery, strQry
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try something like the following, not as easy as you want, but at first look its what I'd try.  I'll continue to look though.

```
Dim f As Form
Dim x As Excel.Application

Set f = Me.Child0.Form

Set x = New Excel.Application
x.Visible = 1
x.Workbooks.Add
x.Worksheets(1).Range("a1").CopyFromRecordset f.Recordset

x.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "filename"
x.ActiveWorkbook.Close False

Set f = Nothing
Set x = Nothing
```

Or create a temp query with the same SQL, and then export this, then delete it.  Not sure on what's allowed.